# How to get x,y coordinates on clicking on Google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I want x,y coordinates for the pixel which I click on the google maps using jquery..
How to get it? I can only get the Latitude and longitude values..
But I need left, top positions..

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click event's PageX, PageY will give the left, top position.

```
$('#map-canvas').click(function(event) {
        $("#tooltip").css('left', event.pageX);
        $("#tooltip").css('top',event.pageY);
});
```

[Refer this](http://jsfiddle.net/TmGg8/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a click event on the container and the event will have an `offsetX` and `offsetY` on it that are coordinates relative to the container.

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/N66hh/2/

Comment: Nice.. I was thinking of the same solution.. +1

Comment: @Kokila Well, do you have some code all set up? Show us what you got. Set up a fiddle with a map on it. What are you trying to bind it on that has it as undefined?

Comment: [Kindly see this](http://jsfiddle.net/TmGg8/2/) Here, I am showing the corresponding latitude, longitude values in a small box when a particular place is clicked. I want this small box to appear near the place where am clicked. This is my need for getting x, y coordinates of clicked place..

Comment: @Kokila In principle, it actually works. http://jsfiddle.net/TmGg8/4/ In practice, Google Maps API draws a bunch of `<div>`s in the canvas (represented by blue outlines), and the event offset from there is based off of that child-most div. It could be modified to get from the parent (`#map-canvas`), but it would be a bit tricky to pull off.